# Transformation and CDF method (standard normal)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ is standard normal and $Y = \begin{cases} {-X} & \text{$X < 0$} \\ \sqrt{X} & \text{$X \geq 0$}\end{cases}$

a) Can the transformation method be used to find the pdf of Y? If yes, find the pdf of Y using the transformation method.

b) Find the pdf of Y using the CDF method.

---

For part a, I said you can't use the transformation method since the graph is not monotonic, right?

For part b, I'm struggling to use the CDF method. I know I'll have to take the derivative with respect to $y$ at some point, but I'm having trouble starting off (finding the CDF).

Comment: What is "monatomic" graph?

Comment: Strictly increasing or strictly decreasing

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has abandoned it.

Answer (score 0):

For $y\ge 0$,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(Y\le y)&=\mathsf{P}(Y\le y,X< 0)+\mathsf{P}(Y\le y,X\ge 0) \\
&=\mathsf{P}(X\ge -y,X<0)+\mathsf{P}(\sqrt{X}\le y,X\ge 0) \\
&=\Phi(y^2)-\Phi(-y).
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\Pr(Y>0) = 1.$

For $x\ge0,$ we have
\begin{align}
F_Y(x) & = \Pr( Y\le x) = \Pr( (X<0\ \&\ Y\le x) \text{ or } (X\ge0\ \&\ Y\le x)) \\[10pt]
& = \Pr(X<0\ \&\ -X\le x) +\Pr(X\ge0\ \&\ \sqrt X \le x) \\[10pt]
& = \Pr(X\le -x) + \Pr(0\le X\le x^2) \\[10pt]
& = \Phi(-x) + \Big( \Phi(x^2) - \Phi(0)\Big) = \Phi(-x) + \left( \Phi(x^2) - \frac 1 2 \right).
\end{align}
You can differentiate this to get the p.d.f., recalling that

- $\dfrac d {dx} \Phi(x) = \varphi(x) = \dfrac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2},$ and
- Use the chain rule as necessary, and
- This applies when $x\ge0.$

Comment: What is the phi? Is there another notation for that? I haven't seen that used in class

Comment: @Hello : $$ \begin{align} \varphi(x) & = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} \text{ is the standard normal density;} \\  \\ \Phi(x) & = \int_{-\infty}^x \varphi(u)\,du \text{ is the cumulative distribution function.} \\  \\  \text{So } \Phi'(x) & = \varphi(x). \\  {} \end{align} $$